# Am I correct that ApolloClient caches my query, -- even across components -- so useContext isn't necessary?

Tags: reactjs, caching, apollo-client, use-context

I have an ApolloClient performing a query through useQuery.

I'd like that object to be available to the whole app, without having to re-fetch it from the database. So I was implementing useContext.

However, i remembered that ApolloClient caches its results.

So if I have this line of code:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USER);
```

and I repeat that line of code across *multiple components*, will the components further down the tree just access the *cached* version? Basically negating the need for useContext?

Thank you.

here's my client config:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: graphql_url,
    fetch: async (uri: string, options: any) => {
      options.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${realmUserToken}`;
      return fetch(uri, options);
    },
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```